# .airflowignore file is not able to hide DAG

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

We have airflow with GCP composer of version 2.2.3.
In airflow we have 2K DAG files where only 100 are Parent Dag's and need to be visible. Rest all are part of taskgroup.

But on airflow UI all 2K files are visible, which is not expected, we expecting only 100 files to be visible.

Any help very useful

Regards
Manoj

we have .airflowignore file in airflow root directory.
We follow all the correct syntax.
but still it is not able to hide DAG's

any help?

Comment: Manoj, Can you  please add a screenshot or explain a bit more ? I didnt understand your question